# Inserting ',' based on conditionals within a STR - Python

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

I am working with a very long list of street names that look like this:

```
1820 W 9000 SWest Jordan
455 S 500 ESalt Lake City
555 S 200 WBountiful
1000 N Green Valley PkwyHenderson
10100 W Tropicana AveLas Vegas
10305 S 1300 ESandy
10600 Southern Highlands PkwyLas Vegas
10616 S Eastern AveHenderson
111 Coors Blvd NWAlbuquerque
1170 E Gentile StLayton
1174 W 600 NSalt Lake City
1200 W Main StRiverton
....
....
```

I am trying to insert a ',' before the city name, which it appears is always after a lowercase character followed by NO SPACE and an UPPERCASE character.

So this is my thinking:

How do I write something that says, more or less,:

```
for cities in lst:
    if [char] is lower and [nextchar] is UPPER:
        [insert] ',' before UPPER
```

Comment: Plus a space in between, probably? And what about `1174 W 600 NSalt Lake City`?

Comment: This looks like someone forgot to put in a space or tab between the street and the city here.

Comment: Yeah, it's all data scraped from the web so unfortunately I can't go back to the data to solve this.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's a rather unfortunate problem here. You could pick the last uppercase letter in a series of uppercase letters at the start of a word as the start of a city name, I suppose.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIGO

Comment: I'm not sure if this is appropriate for your situation (legalities, engineering time, etc considered) but you could run it through the Google Maps API to translate it to valid data. If you take `S Eastern AveHenderson` and map it on Google Maps it corrects it automatically for you with manual search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
for big_index, cities in enumerate(lst):
    for index, char in enumerate(cities):
        if char == char.lower() and cities[index+1] != cities[index+1].lower():
            lst[big_index] = cities[:index] + "," + cities[index:]
```

Disclaimer** Not tested. Since I don't have all your data, I won't attempt it, but this should give the output you're describing

**Edit: In fact, it doesn't look like your data follows these rules at all. Like the example in the comments, what about `Coors Blvd NWAlbuquerque`? Anyway, I'll keep the code here unless you change your question

Comment: I think you want `cities[:index+1]` and `cities[index+1:]`.

Answer (score 4):

Following @Martijn's suggestion to take the last uppercase letter in a group, maybe:

```
import re
def fix(s):
    return re.sub("([a-z]|[A-Z]+)([A-Z])",r"\1,\2", s)
```

which gives

```
>>> for line in lines:
...     print fix(line)
...     
1820 W 9000 S,West Jordan
455 S 500 E,Salt Lake City
555 S 200 W,Bountiful
1000 N Green Valley Pkwy,Henderson
10100 W Tropicana Ave,Las Vegas
10305 S 1300 E,Sandy
10600 Southern Highlands Pkwy,Las Vegas
10616 S Eastern Ave,Henderson
111 Coors Blvd NW,Albuquerque
1170 E Gentile St,Layton
1174 W 600 N,Salt Lake City
1200 W Main St,Riverton
```

[Disclaimer: I'm terrible with regexes.]

Comment: Yet you nailed it... :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
cities = [re.sub(r'(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', ',', x) for x in cities]
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a solution without regex, basically implementing your logic:

```
new_list = []
for line in big_list:
    for c in xrange(len(line)-1):
        if 97 <= ord(line[c]) <= 122 and 65 <= ord(line[c+1]) <= 90:
            line = line[:c+1]+","+line[c+1:]
            break
    new_list.append(line)

>>> new_list
['1820 W 9000 SWest Jordan', '455 S 500 ESalt Lake City', '555 S 200 WBountiful', '1000 N Green Valley Pkwy,Henderson', '10100 W Tropicana Ave,Las Vegas', '10305 S 1300 ESandy', '10600 Southern Highlands Pkwy,Las Vegas', '10616 S Eastern Ave,Henderson', '111 Coors Blvd NWAlbuquerque', '1170 E Gentile St,Layton', '1174 W 600 NSalt Lake City', '1200 W Main St,Riverton']
```

In case you're wondering what the `ord` function does: It translates a character into ASCII code. In ASCII, lower-case letters are bound to 97-122, so if `ord(char)` is in that range, it's a lower-case letter. Same goes for upper-case letters, except they're bound to 65-90.

Answer (score 0):

Your core problem is the missing space between the street and the state portions. Assuming a solution where you have already split this string into component address parts (perhaps using @jazzpi 's solution), you can solve this secondary problem by building a collection of strings that match postal designations, such as `['Ave', 'E', 'Pkwy']` and so on, then look for matches to that collection on the left end of the state string.

Once you find a match, check to see if removing that sub-string leaves the state with an initial capital letter. If it leaves an initial capital letter intact, then you are free to truncate the substring and append the truncated street designation to the street portion.